# How to make emacs ignore some specific file names, for completion?

Tags: file, emacs, completion

In emacs, when im typing the begining of a file name, and then press **tab** for autocompletion, here's what i get :

> Possible completions are:
>
> dummy.cmi  dummy.cmx
>
> dummy.ml   dummy.o

I want emacs to ignore object files (.o, .cmx, .cmi) and directly complete with **dummy.ml**

Is there a way to specify that behaviour in emacs ? some sort .emacsignore mechanism like in **git**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The variable that controls ignored file extensions for completion is `completion-ignored-extensions`. It should already have a couple of extensions in it, but you can add your own.

If you do `M-x customize-variable RET` (i.e. <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>, type `customize-variable` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>)
Then type in: `completion-ignored-extensions` <kbd>Enter</kbd>

You will now get a list of what's already in it. You can also delete entries and add new ones.

You can also add this to your `init.el`/`.emacs`:

```
(add-to-list 'completion-ignored-extensions ".blah")
```

To add multiple elements, instead of duplicating that line:

```
(setq completion-ignored-extensions
    (append completion-ignored-extensions
        (quote
        (".ext1" ".ext2" ".ext3"))))
```